# Ubuntu-touch Webbrowser Virus warning

Tags: ubuntu-touch, malware, webbrowser-app

While using the Webbrowser I got suddenly a hint that a virus is on my Ubuntu Touch Device. My Phone made a beep-beep sound and showed this page:

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Is this true or is it a fake?

Answer (score 0):

i am quite sure that is some virus scam.
I bet they try to make you send or receive a paid sms or such a thing. But i am not aware of a method to harm your sim-card. 
This looks like an overlay Fullscreen Advertisment from back in the days when not everyone was using addBlock on Desktop Browsers.

Comment: Can the Webbrowser really switch to fullscreen without asking? I remember that at the moment the warning appeared I was still able to switch to other apps. I e. The warning was shown by the webbrowser itself.

Comment: See https://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/Andr~Boxer-A/detailed-analysis.aspx

This seems to be a method since some time now. 

Could work with the informations the Browser gives out to show your language and the generic Touch OS.

Comment: So do I understand right, that my screenshot above shows just a full screen homepage which is generated by my browsers data like'used OS' and preferred language.

Comment: i would say so. i dont know anything besides that screenshot.

Could still be a malicious app that got installed (by you (maybe not knowing its malicious)) but then that should still ask you to get access to stuff like contacts, sending a sms, ... due to the security setup.